# THREAD 1 :EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, this error appears at the handle function in the cpp file at the first line

Tags: c++, sfml

this is a code that creates a chicken invaders game, the game(or whatever part i can do of the game) worked fine when i was just initializing one chicken, but when i made it a 2d array of chickens it showed me this error.

```
RenderWindow window;
int main(int, char const**)
{
    chicken chick[4][7];
    Sprite back;
    Clock clock;
    window.create(VideoMode(1800, 1000), "Menu");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                window.close();

            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();

        }

        Texture texture;
        if (!texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "background.jpg"))
        {
            std::cout << "Error loading texture" << std::endl;
        }

        Time time;
        time = clock.getElapsedTime();
        if (time.asSeconds() >= 0.001)
        {
            chick[4][7].handle(window, clock);
            clock.restart();
        }


        window.clear();
        back.setTexture(texture);
        back.setPosition(0, 0);
        back.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 1800, 1000));
        window.draw(back);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                chick[i][j].initialize(window);
        window.display();
    }
}
///////////////////
this is the app file for the chicken class
using namespace sf;
class chicken
{
private:
    RectangleShape chick;
    bool flag;
public:
    chicken();
    void initialize(RenderWindow &window);
    void handle(RenderWindow & window, Clock clock);
    ~chicken();
};
#endif /* chicken_hpp */
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
this is the cpp file for the chicken class 
using namespace sf;

chicken::chicken()
{
    chick.setPosition(500, 500);
    chick.setSize(Vector2f(200, 200));
    chick.setOrigin(100, 100);
    flag = true;
}
void chicken::initialize(RenderWindow & window)
{
    Texture texture2;
    if (!texture2.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "chicken3.jpg"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading texture" << std::endl;
    }
    chick.setTexture(&texture2);
    window.draw(chick);
}

void chicken::handle(RenderWindow & window, Clock clock)
{
    if (flag) //the error appears here
    {
        chick.move( 10 , 0 ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        chick.move(-10 , 0);
    }
    if (chick.getPosition().x >= window.getSize().x)
        flag = false;

    if(chick.getPosition().x < 0)
        flag = true;
}
chicken::~chicken()
{

}
```

Comment: Where is the error? Please include the entire error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the future please include the entire error message in your question, however the issue here is you are accessing an out of bounds index in your chicken array.

your array size is 4x7 this means your valid indices are 0 - 3 and 0 - 6.

Your handle function is being called on chick[4][7], which is out of bounds.

If you are trying to call that function on only the last chick in the array it would be

```
chick[3][6].handle(window, clock);
```

to call it on every chicken you need a double for loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
    {
        chick[i][j].handle(window, clock);
    }
}
```